# Which XML parser has the most human readable error reporting?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, python-2.7, minidom

There are a lot of ways in python provided by the standard installation to process an XML, even more as external packages, see http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml.

For my project I use `minidom`, it does what I need, but the error reporting is rather telegraphic, for example:

```
no element found: line 7, column 0
```

which is correct but is not very human readable, no hinting to which element might be needed. Because of lack of information, I cannot report the error to an user.

This is just an example but there are more cases where minidom could be more detailed but is not. So I need something detailed, an error detailed enough that I can pass the parsing error back to an user.

#### Which of the standard XML „processing solutions” has the most detailed error reporting, if none which of the external packages for XML support has that?

The xml file that was used for parsing, which in the code is used as `config.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
<name>sample</name>
```

Comment: Why don't you try some? A virtualenv with BeautifulSoup and lxml is set up in a snap.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Probably that's what I'll do, but I thought I shouldn't reinvent the wheel and ask first.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Reinvented the will, tryied some of the parsers, see  the answer, you were right about lxml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to do a survey on all the parsers from the above link to see which one has the most useful error reporting, I stopped at lxml:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as  md
md.parse("config.xml")
#xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 7, column 0


import elementtree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("config.xml")
#xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 7, column 0


from xml import sax
parser = sax.make_parser()
parser.parse("config.xml")
#xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: config.xml:7:0: no element found


import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
et.parse("config.xml")
#cElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 7, column 0

import xml.dom.pulldom as pd
doc = pd.parse("config.xml")
for event, node in doc:
     print event, node

#xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:7:0: no element found

import lxml.etree
tree = lxml.etree.parse("config.xml")

#lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag widget line 2, line 7, column 1
```

The conclusion is that `lxml` library had the best error reporting from the above list:

```
"Premature end of data in tag widget line 2, line 7, column 1"
```

Comment: can you check BeautifulSoup too?

Comment: @jterrace: BeautifulSoup uses either the python `HTMLParser` library, or the optional `lxml` or `html5lib` parsers. These are HTML parsers though, not XML, and there is a difference.

Comment: @jterrace: See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: If you're working on large files LXML has a limitation that it won't report row numbers in errors that occur beyond 65535 lines - https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=325533

Comment: @George Luckily in configuration files is rather improbable to get so many lines, thanks for pointing out the limitation